# round up nearest 0.10

Tags: javascript

I need to round up to the nearest 0.10 with a minimum of 2.80

```
 var panel;
 if (routeNodes.length > 0 && (panel = document.getElementById('distance')))   
 {              
   panel.innerHTML = (dist/1609.344).toFixed(2) + " miles = &#163;" + (((dist/1609.344 - 1) * 1.20) + 2.80).toFixed(2); 
 }
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
var number = 123.123;

Math.max( Math.round(number * 10) / 10, 2.8 ).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 8):

If you need to **round up**, use Math.ceil:

```
Math.max( Math.ceil(number2 * 10) / 10, 2.8 )
```

Answer (score 4):

Multiply by 10, then do your rounding, then divide by 10 again

```
(Math.round(12.362 * 10) / 10).toFixed(2)
```

Another option is:

```
Number(12.362.toFixed(1)).toFixed(2)
```

In your code:

```
var panel; 
if (routeNodes.length > 0 && (panel = document.getElementById('distance')))    
{               
    panel.innerHTML = Number((dist/1609.344).toFixed(1)).toFixed(2)
                    + " miles = &#163;" 
                    + Number((((dist/1609.344 - 1) * 1.20) + 2.80).toFixed(1)).toFixed(2);  
}
```

To declare a minimum, use the `Math.max` function:

```
var a = 10.1, b = 2.2, c = 3.5;
alert(Math.max(a, 2.8)); // alerts 10.1 (a);
alert(Math.max(b, 2.8)); // alerts 2.8 because it is larger than b (2.2);
alert(Math.max(c, 2.8)); // alerts 3.5 (c);
```

Comment: @Tuffy G: That's just a random number I plucked out of my head, replace it with the number you want to round to the nearest `.10`.

Comment: @Tuffy G: You can use `Math.max()` method.  I added an example to my answer.

Comment: how would i write that?

i'm sorry to sound like  complete noob

Answer (score 2):

This is a top hit on google for rounding in js.  This answer pertains more to that general question, than this specific one.  As a generalized rounding function you can inline:

`const round = (num, grainularity) => Math.round(num / grainularity) * grainularity;`

Test it out below:

```js
const round = (num, grainularity) => Math.round(num / grainularity) * grainularity;


const test = (num, grain) => {
  console.log(`Rounding to the nearest ${grain} for ${num} -> ${round(num, grain)}`);
}


test(1.5, 1);
test(1.5, 0.1);
test(1.5, 0.5);
test(1.7, 0.5);
test(1.9, 0.5);
test(-1.9, 0.5);
test(-1.2345, 0.214);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var miles = dist/1609.344
miles = Math.round(miles*10)/10;
miles = miles < 2.80 ? 2.80 : miles;
```

Answer (score 0):

to round to nearest 0.10 you can multiply by 10, then round (using `Math.round`), then divide by 10

Comment: how do i write that? its the rounding part i don't know how to

Answer (score 0):

Round to the nearest tenth:

```
Math.max(x, 2.8).toFixed(1) + '0'
```

Round up:

```
Math.max(Math.ceil(x * 10) / 10, 2.8).toFixed(2)
```