# Round half pennies up?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [round up nearest 0.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206335/round-up-nearest-0-10)
> [round number in JavaScript to N decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221167/round-number-in-javascript-to-n-decimal-places)

How can I round floats such as `0.075` up to `0.08` in Javascript? (below half should run down)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206335/round-up-nearest-0-10

Answer (score 9):

You need to multiply by a hundred (so that the cents are what will get rounded), round, then divide by a hundred to get the right price in dollars again.

```
var dollars = 0.075; // 0.075 dollars
var cents = dollars * 100; // ... is 7.5 cents
var roundedCents = Math.round(cents); // ... but should really be 8 cents
var roundedPrice = roundedCents / 100; // ... so it's 0.08 dollars in the end
```

Comment: This will still suffer from some rounding errors. Try 10.075

Answer (score 6):

Use Math.round().  Taken from [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/round.shtml) article

```
var original=28.4531

// round "original" to two decimals
var result = Math.round(original*100)/100;
// returns 28.45

// round "original" to 1 decimal
var result = Math.round(original*10)/10;
// returns 28.5

// round 8.111111 to 3 decimals
var result = Math.round(8.111111*1000)/1000;
// returns 8.111
```

Answer (score 5):

Javascript has three rounding functions, all of which are members of the [`Math`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_math.asp) object: [`round`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_round.asp) (rounds up or down, to the nearest integer), [`floor`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp) (rounds down) and [`ceil`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_ceil.asp) (rounds up). Unfortunately, all three only round to the nearest whole number. However, you can multiply your dollar amount first (to get pennies) and then use `ceil` to round up to the next penny;

```
var money = 0.075;
var pennies = money * 100;
money = Math.ceil(pennies) / 100;
```

Comment: Should be `Math.round` but the idea is the same. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark Your question asked for rounding up... ;)

Comment: I think I asked how to round *half pennies* up, which I suppose is a bit ambiguous for below half ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(0.755.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: `0.075.toFixed(2)` is `0.07`, not `0.08` as requested.

Comment: Okay that is messed up. I mistyped my test code with an extra 5 with FF 3.5.11 javascript:alert( (0.075.toFixed(2)) + "\n" + (0.0755.toFixed(2)) ); Scratching my head on this one. lol

Comment: Very strange http://jsbin.com/uyiho3 Need to see what the spec says. :)

Comment: toFixed bugs in bugzilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=496540  and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588767 man is that inconsistent. lol