# How to trim into 3 decimal places then round it using javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to trim a number into 3 decimal places then round it in 2 decimal places.

For example:

```
1.234567

Trim it to 1.234

Then round it = 1.23
```

Another example:

```
1.389999

Trim it to 1.389

Then round it: 1.39
```

I tried using toFixed() function but it automatically round it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/display-two-decimal-places-no-rounding

Comment: and here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3605973/4454454

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Math.floor` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) to trim it, then the [`Math.round` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) to round it:

```
var n = 1.23456;
n = Math.round(Math.floor(n * 1000) / 10) / 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply the number by a power of 10, use the appropriate math methods, and divide by the same factor.

For rounding, there is [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round):

```
function myRound(num, decimals) {
    var factor = Math.pow(10, decimals);
    return Math.round(num * factor) / factor;
}
```

For truncating, ECMAScript 6 introduces [`Math.trunc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc). For old browsers it can be [polyfilled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc#Polyfill) or, assuming the number will be positive, you can use [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).

```
function myTruncate(num, decimals) {
    var factor = Math.pow(10, decimals);
    return Math.trunc(num * factor) / factor;
}
```

Use them like

```
myTruncate(1.234567, 3); // 1.234
myTruncate(1.389999, 3); // 1.389
myRound(1.234567, 2); // 1.23
myRound(1.389999, 2); // 1.39
```

Comment: The `Math.trunc` method is experimental, not supported in all browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc